# What causes object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) to dispaly on screen?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got a PHP script with an included file with various MySQLi commands to update 2 or 3 different tables within a database.

I have checked my code and have commented out all echo / printf commands, however at various times I have this text displayed on-screen when it shouldn't:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) (and more text that looks like length of
fields, but dont tell me specific field names). { ["current_field"]=>
int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=>
int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

I have also got various/different texts in any DIE commands so I know which die command was activated. (no DIE command has been activated)

My main question is what type of MYSQLI command will cause "object(mysqli_result(#3..."  etc.. to be displayed on the screen without causing an error (or DIE) to be activated ??

As far as i can tell, everything is working perfectly, and i am getting the results i need - Except this unnecessary text to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Because you do `print_r($mysqli_result)`. __Why__ do you do it?

Comment: Sounds like you are outputting an object..without code hard to say though

Comment: That's the output format of [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: You should fetch results calling `result()` method. Did you do that after the `query()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Ive fixed the problem - but i have no idea why / how.

I basically added a number of echo commands throughout the scripts & isolated the function that caused the problem, and the reason / cause of when the function  was activated (i tested 20+ times).

I added various echo commands within the specified function, & removed the echos - but have not altered any  code that was originally in the function, & re-tested the situation.

The only thing i can think of was

```
     // echo "<pre>".print_r($val,true)."</pre>\n";
```

the whole lines (multiple) were already commented out but the display i was seeing was NOT formatted like a PRE statement will display. but, after i put those commands into THREE lines and commented them out. the problem still persisted.

i put echo commands all throughout the function, but could not get it to fix. But after an hour after i fixed the print_r problem, the problem disappeared. I could not identify any other cause.

I'm guessing that the PHP only recognized the comment on the first PRE, but still displayed the print_r

Changed to this - But problem disappeared after an hour. I'm guessing there was a cache problem?

```
     // echo "<pre>"
     // print_r($val,true)
     // echo "</pre>\n";
```

anyway - fixed now.

Comment: Considering that you were getting the [same output format that `var_dump()`](https://3v4l.org/gaSZZ) produces I'm surprised that `var_dump()` wasn't involved at all :-?